# ADF won't update sink after alter row

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm new to ADF but have been having a lot of success.   This one part of my dataflow however will not update the sink no matter what I do.   I have an Azure SQL db table that looks like this. [image]  key'd on acclasscode and acclasscode_effdt.   My transform hits alter row with one record to add an enddate to, and seems right to me.
[image].  When I get to the sink however, and try to write it back nothing happens.    I will say I don't understand why it says 0 rows will be updated up top, but show 1 row to be updated in result set.
[image]

I do have Allow Update on
[image]

Answer (score 0):

AS per [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-alter-row)

> **The actions that you assign to rows (insert, update, delete, upsert) won't occur during debug sessions. Run an Execute Data Flow activity in a pipeline to enact the alter row policies on your database tables.**

I attempted to replicate your same situation and observed the same behavior. The rows tagged `*` that need to be modified are visible to me in the **AlterRow transformation's** data review. However, the sink preview does not appear to be up to date.

- Alter row transformation is the policy you set for the rows you set for them with the expression.
- **Alter row transformation** can result in a row (or rows) being inserted, updated, deleted, or upserted (DDL & DML actions) **against your database only**.

**You need to run the pipeline and execute the activity to see the change in data in database.**